# Why does apropos and man -k omit or miss valid results?

Tags: command-line, man, coreutils, apropos

For example, if I enter the following command:

```
$ man -k compare
```

The `diff` command is missing from the results, however the `test` command is not. I get the same results using `apropos` as expected.

```
$ whereis diff
diff: /usr/bin/diff /usr/share/man/man1/diff.1.gz
$ whereis test
test: /usr/bin/test /usr/share/man/man1/test.1.gz
```

If I examine the short description of `diff`, it is the following:

```
NAME
       GNU diff - compare files line by line
```

As you can clearly see, "compare" is in the short description. Moreover, let's examine the long description too:

```
DESCRIPTION
       Compare FILES line by line.
```

And again, "Compare" appears in the description.

Now, let's examine the short description of `test`:

```
NAME
       test - check file types and compare values
```

Which is what I would expect. However, "compare" is missing from the description of test.

So, I'm not clear why `man -k compare` or `apropos compare` do not find `diff`. However I believe it has to do with the output of the `whatis` command:

```
$ whatis diff
diff (1)             - (unknown subject)
$ whatis test
test (1)             - check file types and compare values
```

Now the reason for this discrepancy may be due to the fact that the man page for `diff` has a name that consists of two words "GNU diff" rather than one, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the man pages of the GNU diffutils package. As you suspected, the problem is that they show “GNU diff” (etc.) rather than just “diff” as the program name. This causes the man program not to recognize the short description.

```
python3
>>> import dbm
>>> db = dbm.open('/var/cache/man/index.db')
>>> db['diff\0']
b'-\t1\t1\t1554725040\t0\tA\t-\t-\tgz\t\x00'
>>> db['cat\0']
b'-\t1\t1\t1567679920\t0\tA\t-\t-\tgz\tconcatenate files and print on the standard output\x00'
```

The bug was introduced somewhere after diffutils 3.3 and before diffutils 3.6. It was reported as [bug #39760](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=39769) and fixed in [this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/commit/?id=9c1447f661922abba208066a07909c5918db0d36) or actually possibly [this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/commit/?id=91eebc4b86d5815c8f76b7315ee065392e109600). The fixes aren't in a release yet, they will be in diffutils 3.8.